# how can i push price into object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
Purchasedata.find(function(err, purchasedatas) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    }
   
    var totalprice = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < purchasedatas.length; i++) {
        findProduct(i, function(i, price) {
        });
    }
    
    function findProduct(i, callback) {
        
        Productpointallocation.find({
            'productcode': purchasedatas[i].ItemCode
        }).exec(function(err, productpointallocations) {
            
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }

            var pointMultiplier = 0;
            if (!productpointallocations) {
                pointMultiplier = 0;
            } else if (productpointallocations.length == 0) {

                pointMultiplier = 0;

            } 

            if (pointMultiplier >= 0) {

                var totalprice = (parseFloat(purchasedatas[i].ItemCost.value)) / 10 * pointMultiplier;
      purchasedatas.push({price:totalprice,productname:productpointallocations[0].productname});
    
                
      console.log(purchasedatas);
                
            }

        });
    }
});
```

In purchasedata i am getting two objects

```
[ { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f40,
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
   },
  { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f3f,
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    }]
```

based on ItemCode i am calculating price. after calculating price i want push price and product name into purchasedatas object

```
purchasedatas.push({price:totalprice,productname:productpointallocations[0].productname});
```

i wrote above code but i am getting object like this

```
[ { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f40,
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
   },
  { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f3f,
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    },
  { price: 4.5, productname: ' ADAPTER-PCS' } ]
[ { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f40,
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
    },
  { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f3f,
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    },
  { price: 4.5, productname: 'ADAPTER-PCS' },
  { price: 1, productname: 'UNIVERSAL AC DC ' } ]
```

my expectation result after pushing price and productname

```
[ { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f40,
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
    price: 4.5,
    productname: 'ADAPTER-PCS'
   },
  { _id: 592fbd65304a7315f87d3f3f,
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    price: 1, 
    'productname: 'UNIVERSAL AC DC '
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about pushing, but about "joining" 2 objects into 1 array element - not tested but "Object.assign" should do the trick.

```js
Purchasedata.find(function(err, purchasedatas) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    }
   
    var totalprice = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < purchasedatas.length; i++) {
        findProduct(i, function(i, price) {
        });
    }
    
    function findProduct(i, callback) {
        
        Productpointallocation.find({
            'productcode': purchasedatas[i].ItemCode
        }).exec(function(err, productpointallocations) {
            
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }

            var pointMultiplier = 0;
            if (!productpointallocations) {
                pointMultiplier = 0;
            } else if (productpointallocations.length == 0) {

                pointMultiplier = 0;

            } 

            if (pointMultiplier >= 0) {

                var totalprice = (parseFloat(purchasedatas[i].ItemCost.value)) / 10 * pointMultiplier;
     purchasedatas[i] = Object.assign({},purchasedatas[i], {price:totalprice,productname:productpointallocations[0].productname});
    
                
      console.log(purchasedatas);
                
            }

        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: it seems that there's some mongo object instead of simple key-value pairs. Try something like that:

```
if (pointMultiplier >= 0) {

                var totalprice = (parseFloat(purchasedatas[i].ItemCost.value)) / 10 * pointMultiplier;
              purchasedatas[i] = Object.assign({},JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchasedatas[i])), {price:totalprice,productname:productpointallocations[0].productname});


               console.log(purchasedatas);

            }
```

or

```
if (pointMultiplier >= 0) {

                var totalprice = (parseFloat(purchasedatas[i].ItemCost.value)) / 10 * pointMultiplier;
              purchasedatas[i] = Object.assign({},tojson(purchasedatas[i]), {price:totalprice,productname:productpointallocations[0].productname});


               console.log(purchasedatas);

            }
```

Comment: i am not getting proper output getting like this [ { '$__':
     InternalCache {
       strictMode: true,
       selected: {},
       activePaths: [Object],
       fullPath: undefined,
       emitter: [Object] },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc:
     {
       ItemCost: [Object],
       PurchaseQuantity: [Object],
       ItemCode: '10',
        },
    price: 4.5,
    productname: 'ADAPTER-PCS' },
  { 
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    } ]

Comment: i am getting like this [ { 
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
    },
  { 
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
 price: 1,
    productname: 'UNIVERSAL AC DC ' } ]
[ { 
    ItemCode: '10',
    PurchaseQuantity: 3,
    ItemCost: 15,
    price: 4.5,
    productname: 'ADAPTER-PCS' },
  { 
    ItemCode: '6',
    PurchaseQuantity: 1,
    ItemCost: 5,
    price: 1,
    productname: 'UNIVERSAL AC DC ' } ]

Comment: That seems to be expected result with provided code. You might be getting an error somewhere else.

Comment: i am getting result two times .i want to send res.status(200).send(purchasedatas); that time i am getting  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent bcoz of that for loop

Comment: and.. if you `console.log(purchasedatas.length)` just below `Purchasedata.find(function(err, purchasedatas) {`, what's the result?

Comment: if i put below price and product name missing

Comment: but the `length`, it's 2 or 4?

Comment: length m getting 4

Comment: Ugh, I'm afraid that I'm lost in this explanations, maybe because I don't know where are you calling (res.status). Console.log inside that loop should be called multiple times, and it seems that this part is correct. Maybe your problem is async nature of your code, but there's not enough input to say that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function will append an object to an array. If you want to add attributes to elements that are in the array already, you'll have to modify the objects. To do that you'll need to find the index of the object in the array, for example by looping over it and comparing the id.

If you want to modify all the Objects inside of the array you can also use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: how can i do this can u help me out

Answer (score 0):

You don't say push since the "push" method is only for arrays, but in fact you can add it to the object, for example:

`var obj = {a: 1, b:2}`

`obj["c"] = 3`

and it will be like that:

`obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

Comment: yes you can do that way `purchasedatas["price"] = totalprice ` ;   `purchasedatas["productname"] = productpointallocations[0].productname` @koo005

Comment: okay, so to be clear your question is how to push into the object and we have your expected output and the result that you got, and I have noticed that you have many arrays in your output, in this case you will iterate over the array and you need another loop to iterate over each object and then you will add the attributes to each object (or the only object that meets you conditions) then it will be as the expected, I will right another answer, please consider it @koo005 and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

So here is it how I believe it would happen,
First iterate over the array (purchasedatas) then over each object inside it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < purchasedatas.length; i++) {
    for (var key in obj) {
       if(purchasedatas[i]["ItemCode"] === req.body.ItemCode) {
          purchasedatas[i]["price"] = req.body.price;
          purchasedatas[i]["productname"] = req.body.productname;
       }
    }
}
return purchasedatas;
```

Hope that this is what you want or at least what you are asking for.